# c# sqlite command formatting

Tags: c#, sqlite

In my database I have an entry `ABCCBAA`

And my Query looks like this:

```
    string sql = SELECT * FROM signatures WHERE length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 AND signature LIKE ABCCBAA 
        OR length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 AND signature LIKE _BCCBAA 
        OR length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 AND signature LIKE A_CCBAA 
        OR length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 AND signature LIKE AB_CBAA 
        OR length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 AND signature LIKE ABC_BAA 
        OR length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 AND signature LIKE ABCC_AA 
        OR length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 AND signature LIKE ABCCB_A 
        OR length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 AND signature LIKE ABCCBA_
```

I am searching through a lot of records with this 1 query so pardon the overkill.

I've been trying this query against the W3Schools examples and it works fine when put into context. I know I'm using SQLite and not SQL but not fully there yet with the syntax.

I expect any of those OR statements to fetch the result, but I have not even been able to execute it yet because of syntax errors. At the moment I am getting

> "SQL logic error or missing database
>
> no such column: ABCCBAA"

Why it is using it as a column name? Other examples lead me to believe the query is correct.

I've been playing about with this for a long time now, so it's possibly something simple I'm not grasping correctly.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a sort of fuzzy string matching. There are probably better approaches, if I were you I'd look it up, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: `_` matches a single character, so your query can never match something of a different length.

Comment: @TimS. Thanks for pointing me to fuzzy matching, I'll see what can be done within sql queries. And with regards to lengths I have accommodated the problem with some more ugly code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the string, for example:

```
WHERE length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 AND signature LIKE 'ABCCBAA'
```

Also, you don't need so many `OR length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8`. Just do something like:

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM signatures 
               WHERE length(signature) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 
               AND (signature LIKE 'ABCCBAA' OR signature LIKE '_BCCBAA' ...)";
```

Comment: I've tried doing that, but get a whole load of different syntax errors, the quotations play havoc, and escaping it with .Replace("'",@"''"), or as a parameter doesn't work, it never maps properly. I will try again anyway.

Comment: Instead of escaping, you should use SQL Parameters

Comment: Well that was silly... Solved all my problem by parameterising it properly. Thanks for the tips, I'll see what I can do to make it non-ugly.